# MongoDB 3.0.1 mongodump error

Tags: mongodb, error-handling, database

I need to create a dumpfile of a MongoDB db using 'mongodump'.

```
    ubuntu-0864947@ubuntu-vm:~$ mongo
    MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
    connecting to: test
    Server has startup warnings: 
    2015-03-30T14:26:08.806+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
    2015-03-30T14:26:08.807+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2015-03-30T14:26:08.807+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2015-03-30T14:26:08.807+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
    2015-03-30T14:26:08.808+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
    2015-03-30T14:26:08.808+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    > mongodump
    2015-04-30T15:56:00.719+0200 E QUERY    ReferenceError: mongodump is not defined
        at (shell):1:1
    > mongodump RotterdamHaven
    2015-04-30T15:56:15.970+0200 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    > use RotterdamHaven
    switched to db RotterdamHaven
    > mongodump RotterdamHaven
    2015-04-30T16:26:13.742+0200 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: `mongodump` is a command line tool. Instead of using `mongo`, type in `mongodump`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mongodump` is an executable like `mongo`, you need to execute it in the OS shell, not in the MongoDB shell:

```
ubuntu-0864947@ubuntu-vm:~$ mongodump <arguments>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Go to bin Directory of Mongodb (mycase : c:\mongodb\bin)
Then,
Run : following Command
mongodump --db database_name

Then go to Dump Directory Created inside Bin Folder

There you'll find folder of your named database and inside that 
 .bson & .json file would be there just keep it safe .bson is your backup file

Cheers